# Italics is to italicize, as bold is to...?

Tags: technical

I'm trying to find the right phrasing for I actionably make something bold in a given text document.  Clearly I know that when I put something in "italics", I'm actionably "italicizing" something, but I haven't been able to easily nor readily find on the internet what I use for when I make something "bold" in a document.

Is it "to *embolden*"?

Comment: Collins English Dictionary gives "bold" as a verb but Collins COBUILD, Lexico, and M-W don't. Scroll down: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bold

Comment: _Boldface_ is the verb I'd use. _Boldface the brand name, but not the corporation_

Answer (score 0):

If you confine yourself to dictionary definitions the answer to your question is "No, it isn't to *embolden*".  The Cambridge online dictionary defines that to mean

> to make someone brave

and offers the sample usage

> Emboldened by drink, he walked over to speak to her.

I expect other dictionaries will provide similar definitions and examples.

But language always runs ahead of dictionaries so feel free to use *embolden* in the sense of making text bold.  In a sentence such as *Embolden text which is to be brought to the reader's special attention.* there is little possibility of misinterpretation.  And, should you find contumely heaped upon you for your (mis)use of English, deal with it as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks!  It was more for the utility, indeed, than the actual proper use of the term.  Thanks again!